# How is the batch asynchronous approach with the intuit SDK any different to the batch synchronous approach?

Tags: asynchronous, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I have looked at the documentation for both synchronous and asynchronous approaches for the QuickBooks Online API V3. They both allow the creation of a data object and the adding of requests to a batch operation followed by the execution of the batch. In both the documentations they state:

> "Batch items are executed sequentially in the order specified in the
>   request..."

This confuses me because I don't understand how asynchronous processing is allowed if the batch process executes each batch operation sequentially.

The documentation for asynchronous processing states at the top:

> "To asynchronously access multiple data objects in a single request..."

I don't understand how this can occur if batch operations are executed sequentially within a batch process request.

Would someone kindly clarify.

Comment: IPP supports only sequential order- synchronous batch operations for the QBO services! Even if you send async requests, it would be of no use as the in reality batch operations are still sequential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In asyn call( from devkit ), calling thread doesn't wait for the response from service. You can associate a handler which will take care of that.

for Ex -

```
public void asyncAddAccount() throws FMSException, Exception {

    Account accountIn = accountHelper.getBankAccountFields();
    try {
        service.addAsync(accountIn, new CallbackHandler() {
            @Override
            public void execute(CallbackMessage callbackMessage) {
                callbackMessageResult = callbackMessage;
                lock_add.countDown();
            }
        });
    } catch (FMSException e) {
        Assert.assertTrue(false, e.getMessage());
    }
    lock_add.await();
    Account accountOut = (Account) callbackMessageResult.getEntity();
    Assert.assertNotNull(accountOut);
    accountHelper.verifyAccountFields(accountIn, accountOut);
}
```

Server always executes the requests sequentially. 
In a batch, if you specify multiple operations, then server will execute it sequentially (top - down).

Thanks